# Reading Austrian public record?

Tags: 20th-century, palaeography, austria

[image]

This is a mention on a public record in Vienna, AT around 1916.

How can you help me reading additional mentions in 1928, 1939 and 1940?

---

Context is Matricula online from a church record in Vienna, St Brigitta for a woman. ([Matricula Online, Wien, rk. Erzdiözese (östl. Niederösterreich und Wien) 20., St. Brigitta](http://data.matricula-online.eu/en/oesterreich/wien/20-st-brigitta/))

This person being born in 1916, 1928 is very coherent as a confirmation.

1939 could be a wedding knowing that it is supposed to have been very short. The man supposedly died a few month later.

I don't know how to get more data on this wedding as Matricula doesn't open records of less than 100 years.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is supplementary ("a mention") to a 1916 church record:

> Gefirmt? 27 V. '928
>  A. fide? Defiat?
>   27. VII 1939
>  S.115/39 B.H.III.
>  Zivilgetraut am 
>   9.5.1940, 812/40

right column note:

> Fr. A. 6 Wien 3, 
>  1 Ehe

The image has 3 sets of different handwriting, apparently 3 events:
Confirmation? in 1928
Probably the church marriage in 1939 (with the reference number)
and the civil marriage in 1940 (with the reference number)

Note may be reference to the parish in Vienna where the marriage took place

---

In response to the edited question:
Since more recent official and church records are restricted for privacy reasons, look for other types of records. Local newspapers probably published notices of both marriages and deaths. According to [ANNO - AustriaN Newspapers Online](http://anno.onb.ac.at/), Vienna newspapers are online to 1947. Your searches will have to determine whether the particular issue with the desired reports is accessible.

Comment: The very first word is probably "gefirmt", confirmed. The rest seems to be cross-references.

Comment: Always good to have a 2nd opinion. I had considered Gefirmt but it looked more like rt at the end than mt. And we still don't have context.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. Context is Matricula online from a church record in Vienna, St Brigitta for a woman. This person being born in 1916, 1928 is very coherent as a confirmation. 1939 could be a wedding knowing that it is supposed to have been very short. The man supposedly died a few month later.